# My report becomes a mess after getting excel export

Tags: c#, reporting, stimulsoft

I have got a Stimulsoft report like this:
[image]
once I get excel export, it becomes a mess like this
[image]

As you can see, the order of columns and blank columns between some columns were created.

And other report return nothing or blankpage
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1- "with" and "left" of each column should be same in header band(or column band) and data band
2-You have 6 text box in header band . you must set "with" and "left" of them as a data band 
3- If you have a footer band(or group footer or footer page), you must set "with" and "left" as data band 
[image]